# Android themed (monochrome) icon doesn't appear on release build

Tags: android, icons, adaptive-icon

It works on emulator devices and I can see themed icon. But on my real device, it doesn't seem to work while other apps are just fine. My real device is Pixel 6 Pro with the latest Android version. Emulators are also with the latest Android version. Themed icon feature is enabled on Pixel launcher.

Anyone faced such issue, I need help..

I created a monochrome version of the icon and added as asset and named ic_launcher_monochrome_foreground.png and updated ic_launcher.xml file in mipmap-anydpi-v26 as:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<adaptive-icon xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <background android:drawable="@color/ic_launcher_background"/>
    <foreground android:drawable="@mipmap/ic_launcher_foreground"/>
    <monochrome android:drawable="@mipmap/ic_launcher_monochrome_foreground"/>
</adaptive-icon>
```

But it only works on emulators. No release build can show the monochrome icon. I cleared the cache of Pixel Launcher on my phone, tried to restart it but none helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We had this issue as well, but realized we only added monochrome for the resource used by `android:icon` (in `application`-tag of our manifest) and not for the resource used by `android:roundIcon`.

Comment: can you please add example files to make this change work completely?

Comment: I can try, but not too easy in comments :) In your manifest you could have something like this: `<manifest ...> ... <application android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher" android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round" ...> ... </manifest ...>`. In that case it's important to add `monochrome` to both `ic_launcher` and `ic_launcher_round`. We first only added to one of the two and then it doesn't work on all devices.